# How to use samel 2 token to authenticate with WEB API 2016 CRM service

Tags: php, authentication, adfs, ws-federation, ws-trust

I have successfully got a security token (samel2.0) by comply to the ws-trust specification. What I cannot continue how can I use this token to access my service (CRM 2016 web api)?

Here's the token I have got:

```
<encryptedassertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<xenc:encrypteddata xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmle..." type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmle...">
<xenc:encryptionmethod algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmle..."/>
<keyinfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmld...">
<e:encryptedkey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmle...">
<e:encryptionmethod algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmle...">
<digestmethod algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmld..."/>
</e:encryptionmethod>
<keyinfo>
<ds:x509data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmld...">
<ds:x509issuerserial>
<ds:x509issuername>CN=*.crm.maxtrain.com</ds:x509issuername>
<ds:x509serialnumber>...</ds:x509serialnumber>
</ds:x509issuerserial>
</ds:x509data>
</keyinfo>
<e:cipherdata>
<e:ciphervalue>...</e:ciphervalue>
</e:cipherdata>
</e:encryptedkey>
</keyinfo>
<xenc:cipherdata>
<xenc:ciphervalue>...</xenc:ciphervalue>
</xenc:cipherdata>
</xenc:encrypteddata>
</encryptedassertion>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me simply I have added the token as a Bearer token with the HTTP header message like this format `Authorization: Bearer <xml token>`. So per http request you have to include that header.